# Best practice for selecting two columns

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have some query like below

```
var email= (from c in dataContext.tblC
            where (c.AA == aa)
            select c.email).ToList();
string emails = email.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);
```

Now I need another column SecEmail, I can't just (...select c.email, c.SecEmail).ToList().
Any suggestion for I can get list like (email1, SecEmail1, email2, email3, SecEmail3, email4...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're working with dynamic objects:

```
var email = (from c in dataContext.tblC
             where c.AA == aa
             select new {
               email = x.email,
               secemail = c.secEmail,
               // ...
             }).ToList(); // IList<dynamic> & IDE will know what properties
                          // you supplied in the `select new { }`
```

Otherwise build a model and populate it:

```
public class SelectModel
{
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String secemail { get; set; }
}

var email = (from c in dataContext.tblC
             where c.AA == aa
             select new SelectModel {
               email = x.email,
               secemail = c.secEmail,
               // ...
             }).ToList(); // IList<SelectModel>
```

If you want the returned rows turned in to an email `to` header:

```
var email = String.Join(", ", (
              from c in dataContext.tblC
              where c.AA == aa
              select c.email
            ).AsEnumerable());
```

Which would make:

```
+------------------+
| email            |
|------------------|
| foo@contoso.com  |
| bar@contoso.com  |
| baz@contoso.com  |
+------------------+
```

Turn in to:

```
foo@contoso.com, bar@contoso.com, baz@contoso.com
```

---

Multi-column concat:

```
var email = (from c in dataContext.tblC
             where c.AA == AA
             select new { email = c.email, secEmail = c.secEmail }).AsEnumerable();
var to = String.Join(", ",
    email.Select(x => x.email)
        .Concat(email.Select(y => y.secEmail))
        // .Concat(eail.Select(y => x.thirdColumn))
        // ...
);
```

Comment: Thanks. but how can I convert email to array list? so I can get list like (email1, SecEmail1, email2, email3, SecEmail3, email4...). actually I need a string to send email

Comment: ohh, i mis-understood. you want the columns concatenated? just simply `String.Join(", ", (from c in dataContext.tblC where c.AA == aa select c.email).AsEnumerable());`

Comment: Thanks but you just select String.Join email, where is the secEmail? And someone has secEmail, someone don't.

Comment: Thanks. but how to add secEmail to the list?

Comment: @MikeLong: sorry for delay; check out last part of my answer

Comment: Thank you very much Brad.that's exactly what I want. That's very helpful.

Comment: within the concat, use `.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.secEmail))`